# How to set up dependency rules?

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis, ndepend, fxcop-customrules, dependency-rule

I want to set up some new dependency rules for a repo which has multiple solutions and assemblies. Rule should be, such as:- in any project,  all the assemblies of type *.ABC.* should not depend upon *.XYZ.*. Any violation of such rule should be caught either during building an assembly or during CI.

1.I tried NsDepCop. There I created a config.NSDepCop file for rules. But the ‘config.nsdepcop file’s build action is not set as C# analyzer additional file due to which Visual studio is unable to detect config.nsdepcop file as C# analyzer file and on building the solution the dependency rules analyzed.

Another ways are "Custom Roslyn rules", "Resharper", FxCop custom rules and NDepend but I have little to no idea about these.

Could anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

With NDepend [a rule is a C# LINQ query](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/write-your-own-code-rules) with a special rule header `warnif count > 0`. Thus the rule mentioned in the question can look like:

```
// <Name>Assemblies ABC shouldn't use Assemblies XYZ</Name>
warnif count > 0 

let asmABC = Application.Assemblies.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("ABC"))
let asmXYZ = Application.Assemblies.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("XYZ"))

from a1 in asmABC.UsingAny(asmXYZ)
select new { a1, xyzUsed = a1.AssembliesUsed.Intersect(asmXYZ) }
```

Of course you can refine the `Where(a => ...)` clauses to your exact context.

---

**Running the Dependency Rule after Building and in CI**

NDepend code rule(s) can be validated:

- [within Visual Studio](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/validating-cqlinq-code-rules-in-visual-studio#Explorer),
- side by side with VisualStudio or Rider thanks to VisualNDepend.exe
- [within Azure DevOps](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/azure-devops-tfs-vsts-integration-ndepend)
- [within GitHub Action](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-github-action)
- [within TeamCity](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/teamcity-integration-ndepend)
- within any other CI/CD technology ([Jenkins](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/jenkins-integration-ndepend), [Bamboo](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/atlassian-bamboo-integration-ndepend)...) thanks to NDepend.Console.exe

---

**Using the Dependency Rule result to remove a matched dependency**

The rule could be refined to match culprit classes and methods when a dependency is found between an ABC assembly and a XYZ assembly. However it is more practicable to:

- export the query result to the [NDepend  Dependency Graph](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph)

[image]

- use the [Graph coupling feature](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Coupling) to visualize why a dependency exists between an ABC to XYZ assembly.

[image: NDepend Coupling Graph feature]

Comment: Thank you so much. This was of great help.

Answer (score 2):

There's a project file snippet<sup>[(source)](https://github.com/realvizu/NsDepCop/blob/5da96a40366cc8843029f4cac5e373815c087729/source/NsDepCop.NuGet/build/NsDepCop.targets#L5)</sup> in the NsDepCop nuget package that automatically marks the 'config.nsdepcop' file in the project folder as 'C# analyzer additional file'. So it should just work.

If it doesn't, then please open an issue at https://github.com/realvizu/NsDepCop/issues so we can ask for more info for reproducing the problem.

---